# Time dependence of the momentum operator for a free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, hamiltonian, time-evolution

I was studying *Modern Quantum Mechanics* by Sakurai, and at the page 85, it is given the analysis of a free particle.

There, the author assumes that Hamiltonian is
$$\hat H = \frac{ \hat p ^2}{ 2m},$$

and do things like $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = [p, H] = 0$ etc. and "derives" that $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t) = 0$.

However, there are a couple of contradictory statements that I see there, and all of them resolves if one assumes that $\hat p$ is time-independent, but the author does not state that, but rather claims to derive that. So is there any such implicit assumption on the time dependence of $\hat p$ (or at least an assumption that $[p(t), p(t')] = 0$) in the Hamiltonian of a free particle  ? If not, the following argument invalidates all of the analysis given in the book.

---

First of all, the relation $$\frac{\partial \hat A_H}{\partial t} (t) = \frac{1}{i \hbar } [\hat A_H(t), \hat H(t_0)] + \left( \frac{\partial \hat A}{\partial t} (t) \right)_H $$ holds only for operators **defined** in Heisenberg's picture, i.e if you give us any operator $\hat A(t)$, then we define a new operator $\hat A_h := U^\dagger (t, t_0) \hat A(t) U(t, t_0)$, and the above relation holds only for such operator. Therefore, unless we explicitly define $\hat H = \frac{\hat p_H^2}{ 2m},$ we we cannot derive the same result $\frac{\partial p_H}{\partial t} = [p_H, H] = 0$ because **otherwise** (i.e if $H = \frac{\hat p^2 }{2m } $, where $\hat p$  is the momentum operator in Schrödinger's picture)

we have 
$$\frac{\partial p_H}{\partial t}(t) = [U^\dagger (t,t_0)p(t)U(t,t_0), H(t_0)] + \left ( \frac{\partial p_S}{ \partial t} (t)  \right),$$
and at this point, we need to know whether $\hat p$ is time-dependent or not, because that will determine the time-dependence of $\hat H$, hence the operator $U(t,t_0)$.

At this point, if we make an assumption that $\hat p$ is time-dependent, but $[p(t), p(t')] = 0$, then one can easily show that $\hat p$ and $\hat U$ commutes, and we get $\frac{\partial p_H}{\partial t}(t) = \frac{\partial p_S}{\partial t}(t)$, or if we assume that $p_S$ is time-independent, everything plays nicely.

Comment: @AaronStevens Where does that relation come from ? The book does not mention it ,as far as I can remember.

Comment: @AaronStevens Ok, let me first ask, when you write $\hat p$, do you mean the momentum operator in Schrödinger's picture, or Heisenberg's picture ?

Comment: If the commutator is $0$ then you end up with $\frac{\text d p_H}{\text d t}=\frac{\partial p_H}{\partial t}$. I don't understand the question

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, but before saying that, you need to show that the commutator is zero, but that what I'm rejecting because the equation $\frac{\partial \hat A_H}{\partial t} (t) = \frac{1}{i \hbar } [\hat A_H(t), \hat H(t_0)] + \left( \frac{\partial \hat A}{\partial t} (t) \right)_H$ is derived for operators in Heisenberg's picture **only** ,so you cannot put $\hat p$ instead of $\hat A$, where $\hat p$ is the momentum operator in Schrödinger's picture.

Comment: Then work in the Heisenberg picture. $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ is true in all picture is it not?

Comment: @AaronStevens Well, if $p_S$ is time-independent, $p_H = U_t^\dagger p_S U_t$ does not have to be, so  I wouldn't expect them to be the same.

Comment: @AaronStevens Because $p_S$ and $p_H$ are different operators, and in general, by defining $H = p_H^2 / 2m$, you basically defining totally a new operator. Of course, this new operator might be the one which agrees with experiments, but I don't see any claim or and statement about such an issue.

Comment: So really you are questioning if $H_S=\frac{p_S^2}{2m}$ then does this mean that $H_H=\frac{p_H^2}{2m}$ and if so, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88795/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-onurcanbektas).